# Initiate dynamic form values within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to figure out how to update my dynamic form process to angular.  Pre-angular I would pass a function into the template context.  Within a jade loop I would pass the values into the function which would return an array, which was passed into a jade form mixin.

Form function:

```
test_form: function(some_id){
    return {
        form_action: '/some-page',
        submit_label: 'Submit',
        elements:{
            element_name: {type: 'hidden', value: some_id},
        }
    };
}
```

Jade template:

```
include /base/form

each x in something
    +form(test_form(x.id))
```

Now that I'm using ng-repeat for this loop, I can't create the forms this way.  How could I accomplish this correctly with angular?  If possible I'd like to use my jade form mixin.

Comment: You can have the variable something in scope and leave the code as it is...

Comment: @V31 Do you mean this ```+form(test_form({{x.id}}))```?  Doesn't work, express gives a jade compiling error. Jade is compiled to html.  Angular fires after the page is loaded so they can't talk to each other this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it with something like:

```
<dyno-form ng-repeat="item in something" item="item"><dyno-form>
```

And then define the dynoForm directive's template to look something like

```
<input ng-if="item.type == 'text'" type="text" ng-model="item.model">
<input ng-if="item.type == 'checkboxes'" ng-repeat="boxval in item.checkboxes"> ...
```

etc etc etc. Then you can define your JSON object for the data and pass it in to the dynoform. Manipulating the json model changes the form layout.

Of course, I'm not 100% sure I'd do it just that way; I could see areas where one could extract out some child directives for various types and so on. But the central theme of declaring conditional rendering is what I'm getting at here.